# Is there difference between Linux and Windows utf8 encoding?

Tags: python, windows, encoding

I am programming python over Linux environnement (Ubuntu with pycharm and python 2.7). Everything is working like a charm, then I tried to use my project on Windows 8 environnement.

I've some comments on my code with accent, I then encoded my file in utf8 (anyay that's the best thing to do by default I assume).

**My problem :** 
I have error using my project on Windows saying :

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file C:/Somedirectory/MyFile.py on line 13, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

So I know it is a problem of encoding, but I understand here that Window try to decode ascii encoding when my file is actually in utf8, which does not make sense.

Using text editing software, I found out that my files are in utf8 without BOM, if I am converting in utf8 with BOM, everything if working smoothly.

Are you aware of any difference between Linux and Windows utf8 encoding ? Is Windows not able to detect utf8 without bom ?

Edit : 
Yes I am aware of PEP0263 and using # -*- coding: utf8 -*-

Comment: Did you see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ ???

Comment: You'd get the exact same error on Linux for that source file. You used a non-ASCII character somewhere on line 13 but did not declare your source encoding.

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't require a BOM, but *Windows programs* often do, in that they auto-detect the codec used for a file based on the BOM. Also see the [wikipedia information on the UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8). Python *requires* you to declare the encoding if you do not use the standard codec (ASCII on Python 2, UTF-8 on Python 3).

Comment: As I said Pieters, everything is working perfectly on my Linux environnement. And  I checked the pep-0263 since it is written on the error log. I am respecting whats provided. The problem is that I declare the encoding, but Windows since to ignore it.

Comment: You need to make sure that the coding line is a) correctly formatted and b) the first or second line of your file. If it is neither, then Python will not pick it up.

Comment: @MathiasDesch: then provide us with a reproducible example; what exactly does your file (first few lines) look like? If you can give us a `repr()` version of the binary contents of the file that reproduces this that'd be helpful.

Comment: Also, if you save the file with a UTF-8 BOM, Python throws a syntax error: `SyntaxError: encoding problem: utf8 with BOM`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will provide you an reproducible exemple and trying out some stuff.

Comment: Here is the conclusion : My IDE (Pycharm) is adding at each module the author line `__author__="name"`. Even if the pep0263 is allowing putting the encoding line in second line, it does not work on Windows with this author line above. I just switch the two lines in all my modules and problem is gone.